# What does ‘Limitless is riding the middle ground of CBS' freshman crop’ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context:

> The Bad News: Like anything on CBS, it depends on the needs of the
>   network and available slots. **Limitless is riding the middle ground of
>   CBS' freshman crop** and it doesn't help that Criminal Minds: Beyond
>   Borders is doing slightly better after less than a month on air.

What does the phrase in bold mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down. "Freshman crop" means the shows that are new to CBS this viewing year. It includes any that has started since September 2015 or so. The "middle ground" means that the ratings for the show *Limitless* are average. It's not getting the best nor the worst ratings for CBS "freshman" shows.

Then there's a statement that *Criminal Minds: Beyond Borders* is already getting better ratings even though it premiered in March 2016. All of this is probably part of an article about renewal chances for *Limitless* or other new shows on CBS. Some shows do take a while to find their audience, but if ratings aren't increasing, that's not a good sign.